# System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I try to compile a source code in visual studio when I run the debugging and get this error message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
> occurred in CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for
> 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception.

The code that contains the error

```
Public Sub LoadAdvisory(ByVal lbl As Label)
        ExecuteSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_business")
        If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            lbl.Text = sqlDT.Rows(0)("business_name")
            crpBusinessName.Value = sqlDT.Rows(0)("business_name")
        Else
            lbl.Text = ""
            crpBusinessName.Value = "Business Name"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Inner Exception

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net,
> Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm new in visual studio

Comment: What is the result from `$exception.InnerException` in the debugger? Full message and stack trace. Please [edit] and add to post

Comment: Inner Exception FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: That looks pretty clear, it's missing log4net. Did you use nuget to install `CrystalDecisions`?

Comment: no, i don't use nuget

Comment: Perhaps you should. Either way you need to download and add log4net to your project

Comment: okay, i will do that thank you

Comment: i run this command PM> Install-Package log4net -Version 1.2.10 but i get the same error

Comment: Os log4net now added to your project? Do you have something else that depends on a different version of log4net?

Comment: no, i don't think that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229877/discussion-between-hocine-djouamaa-and-charlieface).

Comment: @HocineDjouamaa what data comes in `ExecuteSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_business") ` , I thnk and based on an error that your crystal report name is not found from proper location (Is this line (crpBusinessName.Value) get the crystal report name and path?)

Comment: you can give the physical path of your report and then try.